# Cardinality of nested sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

which of these is correct:

> Let $A_n$ and $B_n$, $n\in\Bbb N$ be nonempty subsets of $\Bbb R$ such that $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq A_3\supseteq\dots$ and $B_1\subseteq B_2\subseteq B_3\subseteq\dots$. Let cardinality of $A_n$ be $a_n$ and the cardinality of $B_n$ be $b_n$.
>
> 1. Then the cardinality of $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }a_n$,
> 2. Then the cardinality of $\cup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ is $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }b_n$.

Which of 1. and 2. is correct?

I thought about finite cardinalities, because I have only once heard of 'biggest set with countable number of elements'.

Let $B_n=\{1,2.\dots,n\}$, so, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }b_n=\infty$, but $\infty$ is not a cardinality. Is this correct way to approch?

Comment: $$\Huge\textbf{Cardinals are not real numbers!}$$

Comment: @AsafKaragila, :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, so taking limit is superfluous?

Answer (score 2):

1 is false; think about $$A_n = (0,1/n).$$

2 is should be true, for an appropriately chosen topology on the set of cardinal numbers between $0$ and $\beth_1$. But you have to choose the topology first, which is what Asaf's comment is getting at.

[Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number) an explanation of the $\beth_\alpha$ notation; in this context, I'm using $\beth_1$ because it equals the [cardinality of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum).

Comment: Using the notation $\beth_1$ in an answer to a question that was likely to have been asked by someone who doesn't know what $\beth$ numbers are is considered in many cultures a "dick move".

Comment: @AsafKaragila, the asker is free to ask me for clarification on whatever the need a hand with of course. Feel free to answer in your own way if you think this is a bad answer. In any event, I've added a link to the relevant page.

Comment: So instead of writing $2^{\aleph_0}$ or $|\Bbb R|$, you decided that the best solution is to complicate things further by sending the OP to read about $\beth$ numbers? I mean, have you read the post? Does that seem like a valid solution?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, well sure. I'm a very notation-oriented thinker. If someone tells me; here, there's the $\beth$ numbers defined like so, and the $\aleph$ numbers defined like so, and we can't prove they're different using the standard axioms, I'll go: "okay, I get it now." But without a symbol to attach my understanding to, it all remains a bit hazy. I accept that not everyone is like this, but I am.